# jQuery - Create new function on event

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript/jQuery, if I want to have a function that can run on an element that has been appended to the DOM, it has to be created *after* the element has been appended to the DOM. How can I do this? I heard one can do this with the jQuery `.on()` function, but I'm not quite sure how.

*HTML:*

```
<span>Hello Stackoverflow</span>​
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$("span").click(function () {
   addMyElement();
});

$("p").click(function () {
   removeMyElement(this);
});

function addMyElement() {
    $("<p>Hello World</p>").appendTo("body");
}
function removeMyElement(myElement) {
    $(myElement).remove();
}
```

Example on [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/wowpatrick/wWXrK/5/).

Comment: Do you mean an event handler? If so, which event, it may be as simple as adding a call to newElement.click(blah)

Comment: Some good examples of .on here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Just added an example of what I mean ... hope it helps!

Comment: http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html - a comparison of all jQuery event functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called [delegated-events approach](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) and it works as follows:

```
$("body").on("click", "p", function () {
    // ...
});
```

Instead of `body` you can use any parent element of `p`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wWXrK/6/

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right: If inside of the element `body` the event `click` is fired on an element `p`, the functions inside the curly brackets is will be "added"? Or am I getting something wrong? So if I have functions that run on elements that are appended to the page, I just wrap it in your example?

Comment: @wowpatrick Yes, the code inside the so-called *handler* function will be executed.

Answer (score -2):

```
function addMyElement() {
    $("<p>Hello World</p>").appendTo("body").click(function () {
       removeMyElement(this);
    });
}
```

Will work for you, not hugely readable with all that chaining though.